# How to extract Data from url request in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, barcode

I am writing an application to scan barcodes and then query Outpan.com in order to get information from the barcode number. 
How can I extract information from the url request?
Below Is an example of the output after a successful scan. 
How could I store for example the name into a NSString?

This is the code I'm using to access the information.

```
- (void) sendRequest {


NSString *myString = @"https://api.outpan.com/v2/products/";

NSString *secondhalf= _barcode;


NSString *thirdHalf = @"?apikey=935b8b8e102f93220b751a4e1c66126a";

NSString *test = [myString stringByAppendingString:secondhalf];
NSString *text = [test stringByAppendingString:thirdHalf];

if (![text isEqualToString:@""]) {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:text];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];

}

}
```

Normally Id try to use something like

```
   NSString* value = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('myId').value"];
```

if the html looked something like this

```
<html>
  <body>
      <input id="myId" type="text" value="TextValue"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

but the html is like this

```
<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-    wrap;">{
    "gtin": "0014633156720",
    "outpan_url": "https:\/\/www.outpan.com\/view_product.php?    barcode=0014633156720",
    "name": "Battlefield: Bad Company 2",
    "attributes": {
        "Distribution Media\/Method": "Blu-ray Disc",
        "ESRB Rating": "RP (Rating Pending)",
        "Manufacturer": "Electronic Arts",
        "Manufacturer Part Number": "15672",
        "Platform": "PlayStation 3",
        "Platform Supported": "PlayStation 3",
        "Software Main Type": "Game",
        "Software Sub Type": "First Person Shooter"
    },
    "images": [],
    "videos": [],
    "categories": []
}</pre></body></html>
```

[image: WebView]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to make an api request using a UIWebView. The api probably sees your Accepts header as text/html and therefore sends you the api response in a webpage, instead of just raw JSON. Try making the request with NSURLSession instead.

```
- (void)sendRequest:(id)sender {

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://api.outpan.com/v2/products/%@", _barcode];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

    NSURLComponents *components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithURL: url resolvingAgainstBaseURL: NO];

    NSURLQueryItem *query = [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName: @"apikey" value: @"935b8b8e102f93220b751a4e1c66126a"];

    components.queryItems = @[query];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: components.URL];

    request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";

    NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if (error == nil) {

            NSDictionary *responseBody = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: 0 error: nil];

            NSLog(@"got response: %@", responseBody);

        } else {
            // Failure
            NSLog(@"URL Session Task Failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];

    [task resume];
}
```

Not tested because I don't have a real barcode, but you should see the JSON you are requesting in the `responseBody` dictionary.

Comment: the code worked successfully to get the output, how can i now extract the data from responsebody?

Comment: disregard the previous comment totally forgot that i could just use  NSString *str=[responseBody objectForKey:@"name"];